# mySQL Stored Procedure to Set a Calculate field Value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a scenario:

I have like 5 Boolean fields in a table, I need to set an option set value based on the number of true values of those 5 Boolean Fields:

Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
Field5

ENUMField1 values (A,B,C,D,E)

If I have 5 of those Boolean fields as True, I will set the ENUM field  value as A,
4 Trues and I set them as B
and so on

As I may need to change the logic of those values in the future , I need to set/change them on DB side on save ,rather than on controller.

Thanks

As I'm not familiar with stored procedures I couldn't manage to find a solution.

Comment: Hmm 5 fields but 4 enum values? And why do you think a stored procedure would be useful?

Comment: yes, as I will not set a value when I have only 1 True, but I may change that in the future, so we can assume that there are like 5 Enum values. An Stored procedure is better because I may change the logic in the future and I need to set those values in the DB, after the records have been saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe generated column is more suitable? It will provide actual value always, rather than stored procedure which must be executed each time when you need in actual values..

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  Field1 BOOLEAN, 
  Field2 BOOLEAN,
  Field3 BOOLEAN,
  Field4 BOOLEAN,
  Field5 BOOLEAN);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,1,1,1,1),
(1,1,0,1,1),
(1,0,1,0,1),
(1,1,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,1,0),
(0,0,0,0,0);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD COLUMN ENUMField1 ENUM('A','B','C','D','E','F')
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (6-Field1-Field2-Field3-Field4-Field5);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5 | ENUMField1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | B |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | C |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | D |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | E |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | F |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XPwn53bm)

Comment: Yes, Thanks, A generated column is much better

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure is just putting your SQL on the server rather than calling it from the client. There's nothing special about it, and it isn't a way to write logic to run on the server (there are ways to do this, varies on programming language, but the DB is not recommended as a place to store your application code)

You create a SP with the following syntax. Use your own SQL in the middle.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMovies(IN name varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT title, description FROM movies WHERE title LIKE name;
END
```

how you call that varies by your client language, but typically its little different than calling a parameterised SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, I know about Stored Procedures limitations , the field is a custom value which I need to set so I can analyze them , So let's assume I need to ask about some help to write the logic of setting that value based on another values in SQL. (on a SP)
Thanks again for your help, Sorry I Don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your enum runs from A-Z then using ascii conversions where dec 65 is A

```
select * ,
        cast(char(65+abs(col1-1)+abs(col2-1)+abs(col3-1)+abs(col4-1)+abs(col5 -1)) as char(1)) enumval
from t;
```

eg

drop table if exists t;

```
create table t
(col1 tinyint,col2 tinyint,col3 tinyint,col4 tinyint,col5 tinyint, e enum('a','b','c','d')
);

insert into t (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) 
values
(1,1,1,1,1),
(1,1,1,1,0);

+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | e    | enumval |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 | NULL | A       |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 | NULL | B       |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
```

If you have more and more columns then you will need dynamic sql.